# Expand tooltip hover area for questions with >1,000 views

Tags: feature-request, views, tooltips, question-lists

I was just browsing through some of my questions looking at the ones that have more than 1,000 views on them, which get abbreviated to **1 kviews** in the list. The problem I'm having is the tooltip functionality to see the exact number is somewhat irritating. The tooltip only works if you hover over the actual number **1**, which is quite a small area.

> [image: Current Tooltip Area]

Why doesn't the tooltip cover the entire box instead, providing a larger area for users to hover over in order to get the exact number of views? Basically, put the `title` on `div.views` instead, or maybe even on `div.mini-counts`.

> [image: Proposed Tooltip Area]
>   [image: Alternate Proposed Tooltip Area]

Or, if that's not a viable option, change the CSS for that span so that it expands to fill the area of its parent `div.mini-counts` box (what I'm currently using in custom CSS).

```
.mini-counts span { display: block }
```