# Hovering over "kviews" should show the number of views like hovering over a number does

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand tooltip hover area for questions with >1,000 views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158126/expand-tooltip-hover-area-for-questions-with-1-000-views)

On a [profile under the questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61654/ahsteele?tab=questions&sort=views) when a user hovers over the rounded number of views it shows the exact number of views that a question has had. However hovering over "kviews" does not show the exact number of views:

[image]

I realize that not all browsers treat the `title` attribute the same. In that they do not all show a tooltip when it present. However, in the browsers that do not having a tooltip present when hovering over "kviews" feels inconsistent.

It seems that the `title` attribute could be added or moved to solve this issue:

- adding a title attribute to the "kviews" container would mean that hovering of either would show the number.
- moving the attribute to the container div that both "kviews" and the associated number share would show the exact number of views anywhere around the views area.

I will let others figure out which is the more preferable option.

Comment: When I search I didn't find the [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158126/61654). #sigh